# Access Session inside controller but outside ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to access a Session variable in my controller but I cant. 
The variable inside the ActionResult method works properly but the first one dont work.
I want to declare as private variable because im going to use in all actionresults

This is my code

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    private Roles rol = Session["rol"] as Roles;

    // GET: 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Roles rol = Session["rol"] as Roles;
```

---

I edit the topic because i cant add a new question.

---

Thats working on the ActionResult Method.

This is the error that im getting:  [error](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/825x117q90/902/oDN6Er.png)
I tryed adding new usings, tryed to use httpContext and other things but im not doing properly.

Forget about roles.
My question is (on next code): Why c2 variable is working properly, taking data from my session and c1 dont work ?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

    private Clients c1 = Session["client"] as Clients;

    // GET: 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Clients c2 = Session["client"] as Clients;
```

Comment: You should add a tag or two about the framework you are using.

Comment: Ok Sorry im using mvc 5

Answer (score 0):

Looks like .NET MVC. When your application starts there are no session variables. So this line:

```
private Roles rol = Session["rol"] as Roles;
```

cannot work

As soon as a user access your site (and your ActionResult), session variables can be created for him. You can store user roles in a session variable and use it in all your ActionResult functions for the specific user

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
   Session["rol"] = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
   ....
```

maybe tell as what you are trying to achieve so we can help more

Edit:

this line

```
private Clients c1 = Session["client"] as Clients;
```

can not work because it will run when the controller is first used. You simply cannot use a session variable in the initialization of a controller. Session variables exist only after a user creates them and this can be done in an action result. Session Variables are tied to a user.

Is it possible you want to use a simple global variable and not a session?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

private static List<Client> c1 = new List<Client>();

// GET: 
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ....
    // you can access c1 here, change it, etc
    c1.Add(client);
    ....
```

short answer: you are trying to use a variable that has not been created yet

Comment: I added some info to the initial post. Sorry my english is not so good. Hope this time I explained better. Thank you !!